# Correctly defining a Cron schedule for process to be run every hour

Tags: linux, cron, syntax

There is a record:

```
45 * * * 1 script.sh
```

and

```
45 0-23 * * 1 script.sh
```

The desired effect is to run the script 45 minutes after every hour on Mondays.

Are they identical? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: If you remember that the 2nd field is "hours", the 1st is shorter; if you like seeing a reminder, the 2nd is more obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are identical.

I'd suggest the first syntax as it is more concise.

Answer (score 3):

They both work. However, I would personally prefer:

```
45 * * * mon script.sh
```

As it is more readable, and more immediately understandable without having to remember which day of the week is '1'.

Comment: Note that `mon` as a day *name* is a GNU extension to [standard `crontab`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html).  It's not likely available on non-GNU systems.

Comment: Agreed, but nearly all systems use Vixie/ISC cron (or GNU cron if you prefer). That covers Linux and BSD pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

They are identical but prefered to use first variant, there is less chance to get confused.
Generally with its syntax is easy to get confused, [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/top-4-cron-mistakes.html) [is](http://www.alleft.com/sysadmin/common-cron-mistakes/) a some typical mistakes with cron.